# Can a function have a point as a extrema eventhough if it is not differentiable at that point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For example ,if I take f(x) as |x| then it is obvious  that it is not diferentiable at x=0 , but when we draw the graph  of it , it looks as if it is the minima of the whole function. But f'(x) doesn't at x=0 . So, why does it appear  to be a minima , while the condition for extrema fails ? Please don't down vote my question.

Comment: Yes: $y=e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: What may help is to write down your "condition for extrema", paying close attention to hypotheses.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to math.SE! As long as we use a reasonable definition of minima, like

Def: $x$ is a *global minimum* of $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ if $$ f(x) \leq f(y) , \ \text{ for all }\ y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then we can safely say that $0$ is a global minimum of $f(x) = |x|$. The derivative test can be helpful to find extrema, but just because its hypothesis doesn't hold doesn't mean that a point isn't a max/min or that a function doesn't have a max/min.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a minimum because it is a (global) minimum (i.e. it is a point $x$ such that, for all $y$, $f(y)\ge f(x)$).

Differentiable functions have derivative zero at (local) maxima and minima; this is true. Said result applies vacuously to this instance because $f$ isn't differentiable.